# Can Vue.js single-file components be used directly in the index.html file?

Tags: vue.js

I am trying to learn Vue.js and understand SFCs and importing components into other components. The main `App.vue` is mounted/loaded into the `<div id="app"></div>` within an `index.html` file.

However I have come across a tutorial that does this in the `src/index.html` file which I don't understand:

```
<html>
<head>
...
</head>
<body>
   <div id="app">
   <app></app> <!-- how is it possible to include a Vue.js component here?
   </div>
<script src="/dist/bundle.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I don't understand how a regular HTML file can contain reference to a Vue.js component like above. I can't see it being done like this anywhere in the docs.

Comment: its probably because #app have defined other component in js app component definition or component is defined as Vue.Component. Eg you can create global Vue.Component and register and use everywhere or you can create component and define it in app js components property.

Comment: check this https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Base-Example and this https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-registration.html